# Why is my global value in a function return an error when i print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def name():
    global x
    x = "Hello"
    print(x + " Guys!")

print(x)
print(name())
```

the output is

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why is this happening? This is weird because I placed the (global) function.

Comment: Function bodies are not executed until you call it. So `x` is not defined when you are trying to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time print(x) is called outside the function, the function not having been run yet, x is not defined. Once you run name(), then you can print(x) whenever you like.

Comment: @cloroxide - Is this answer sufficient for you? If so, accept it and we'll know that you don't need any more assistance.

Comment: wait a minute i think i have another question, i typed  print(name()) first before print(x) and i works but it prints  (Hello Guys    None    Hello)   Why is that?? sorry if im asking stupid questions but im just starting to program

Comment: You have a `print` in the function, but the function itself returns `None`. With `print(name())`, the function prints "Hello Guys", then returns. Then its return value "None" is printed. Then `print(x)` prints "Hello". Its the same as `foo = name()` followed by `print(foo)` followed by `print(x)`.